# Fancybox autoScale (auto-size) issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have this code

```
<a href="/popup/size-charts.aspx" class="popup">Size Charts</a>
```

and this

```
$('.popup').fancybox();
```

But the popup is always too small on first click

[image]

Second click (and 3rd and so on) is always perfect

[image]

I have tried explicitly setting `autoScale: true`, and calling `$.fancybox.resize()` after the popup is shown, both do nothing.

I have a lot of this kind of popup and want to avoid setting dimensions manually.
Does anyone know any workaround to get the size right from the first time it opens?

Comment: Have you tried adding `data-fancybox-type="iframe"` to your `a` element?

Comment: Hey dunli thanks! I tried making it an iframe but it wouldn't work. How exactly do you make it an iframe?

Comment: Try changing your `a` element to: `<a href="/popup/size-charts.aspx" class="popup" data-fancybox-type="iframe">Size Charts</a>`

Comment: I tried exactly that, but it is still not an iframe. Is there a way to set that option from the javascript?

Comment: [This](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) might help you. Or can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I don't think I can because I have different CSS on both the main page and the popup page. Actually let me get rid of the CSS, it should fix the problem, thanks dunli!

Comment: Yeah, that might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that removing all CSS from the popup page fixed the auto-size issue, although that makes the popup uglier.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention it's 1.3.4